# Dissolve lines with same attributes that are connecting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I have a road network for a city. In that city, I have multiple roads with the same name and each road consists in multi-lines that are connected. In the end, I want a new line for each road, which means if I have three roads that have the same name I will have three parts. I tried dissolve but is not working properly, I tried after dissolve to use multipart to single part but is not what I want.

Comment: How did dissolve "not work properly"? Why is "multipart to single part" not desireable?

Comment: Hi, @Erik.  Thanks for helping.  if there are more than 2 lines connected at the same point then when doing multipart to a single part it's not keeping just a part consisting of that three lines but it creates three parts.

Comment: That still leaves the first question unanswered: How does dissolve "not work properly"? What are your settings? What outcome did you expect, which did you get?

Comment: The combination of them both doesn't bring the expected results. The dissolve work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be the tool Explode Lines-

Under Vector geometry --> Explode Lines

You should have a separate line for each road segment, even if they have the same road name